# How much time SharePoint 2010 take to include site column data changes in search

Tags: 2010, search, crawling, enterprise-search, crawl-external-content

I am implementing search on SharePoint 2010. On the advanced search page, i have added a property restriction named Keyword.

It is connected to a Site Column named Keyword. The site column is of text type and is added in the properties of all the site pages.

Initially i added "Key" in the Keyword Property of some 5 Pages and the search worked fine.
I don't remember i have crawled after this or not.

Later on i added value for keyword property for some more page, but they are not showing in the search result.

I changed the keyword property of initially added pages (to test), but they are available in the search results, when i search "Key".

I want to know does SharePoint will by any chance include these data changes(of site column) in search by itself, or i need to crawl.

If the crawl is must than will an Incremental crawl do the trick or full crawl will be needed.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crawler's have schedule to crawl, they don't just randomly start crawling, and it time depends on how you configured crawler's Schedule. You can check when your crawler crawled last time through Central Admin.

> In the Search service application, you can schedule a full or
>   incremental crawl of a content source. There are four types of
>   Schedules:
>
> DailySchedule - Used to specify the number of days between crawls.
>   WeeklySchedule - Used to specify the number of weeks between crawls.
>   MonthlyDateSchedule - Used to specify the days of the month and months
>   of the year when the crawl should occur. MonthlyDayOfWeekSchedule -
>   Used to specify the days of the month, the weeks of the month, and the
>   months of the year when the crawl should occur. Through UI:
>
> Go to Central Administration => Application Management => Manage
>   service applications => Search Service Application. In the Navigation
>   go to Crawling => Content Sources. You could be able to see the
>   content sources. I am going to edit the content source "Local
>   SharePoint sites" and schedule the crawl. Go to ECB menu of Local
>   SharePoint Sites =>Edit.
>
> You could see "Crawl schedule section" where you could schedule the
>   Full Crawl and Incremental Crawl.

[Source](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/configure-a-crawl-schedule-for-enterprise-search-content-source-in-sharepoint-2010/)

[Crawl content on different schedules](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262926%28v=office.14%29.aspx#section6)